# ¿Cómo añadir un campo agregado de otra tabla a una consulta que ya une varias tablas?

Tags: postgresql, sql

tengo esta consulta de postgrest:

```
SELECT 
u.type AS "userType", 
u.state AS "state", 
u.email AS "email", 
u.cellphone AS "cellphone", 
s.name AS "storeName", 
s.idshop AS "id",
u.iduser AS "idu",  
b.name AS "bank", 
ba.number AS "accountNumber", 
h.name AS "accountHolder", 
h.document AS "documentHolder", 
c.alias AS "coin" 
FROM "banksAccounts" AS ba 
INNER JOIN holders AS h ON ba.idholder = h.idholder
INNER JOIN coins AS c ON ba.idcoin = c.idcoin
INNER JOIN banks AS b ON ba.idbank = b.idbank
RIGHT JOIN shops AS s ON ba.idbankaccount = s.idbankaccount
LEFT JOIN "usersShops" AS us ON s.idshop = us.idshop 
RIGHT JOIN users AS u ON u.iduser = us.iduser  
WHERE s.idshop = '59';
```

Lo que quiero es añadirle a esta consulta otra tabla "paymentsPending" que depende de la tabla "shops"; de "paymentsPending" necesito contar los pagos pendientes de la tienda y su cantidad total de dinero. Estas tablas se relacionan con una llave foranea "idShop" que la tiene "paymentsPending", esta tabla tiene el campo "value" que es la cantidad de dinero. 
Gracias

**Modelo hecho para la pregunta:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, incluye en tu pregunta [(editándola)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/169618/edit) las sentencias DDL (los CREATE TABLE) de las tablas a usar

Answer (score 1):

Hay básicamente 2 formas de lograr lo que buscas.

1. Puedes hacerlo con una sub-consulta, donde lo que haces es escribir un `select` dentro de la sección de columnas de tu `select` inicial, para recoger los datos ya resumidos de otra tabla. Esta opción es más legible, pero depende de las capacidades de optimización del motor para funcionar de manera eficiente. En ocasiones, es la que tendrá peor desempeño. En tu caso, se haría así:

   ```
   SELECT
   u.type AS "userType",
   u.state AS "state",
   u.email AS "email",
   u.cellphone AS "cellphone",
   s.name AS "storeName",
   s.idshop AS "id",
   u.iduser AS "idu",
   b.name AS "bank",
   ba.number AS "accountNumber",
   h.name AS "accountHolder",
   h.document AS "documentHolder",
   c.alias AS "coin"
   , (select count(1)
        from "paymentsPending" as pp
       where pp.idShop = s.idShop
     ) as "ContadorPagosPendientes"
   FROM "banksAccounts" AS ba
   INNER JOIN holders AS h ON ba.idholder = h.idholder
   INNER JOIN coins AS c ON ba.idcoin = c.idcoin
   INNER JOIN banks AS b ON ba.idbank = b.idbank
   RIGHT JOIN shops AS s ON ba.idbankaccount = s.idbankaccount
   LEFT JOIN "usersShops" AS us ON s.idshop = us.idshop
   RIGHT JOIN users AS u ON u.iduser = us.iduser
   WHERE s.idshop = '59';
   ```
2. hacer un join de las tablas, y luego resumir los resultados. Esto se hace utilizando la clausula `group by`, similar al código de abajo. Esta opción suele ser más eficiente, sobre todo tomando en cuenta que quieres recoger no uno, sino dos campos agregados, pero te recomiendo probar ambas en tu motor/configuración para ver cuál se desempeña mejor.

   ```
   SELECT
   u.type AS "userType",
   u.state AS "state",
   u.email AS "email",
   u.cellphone AS "cellphone",
   s.name AS "storeName",
   s.idshop AS "id",
   u.iduser AS "idu",
   b.name AS "bank",
   ba.number AS "accountNumber",
   h.name AS "accountHolder",
   h.document AS "documentHolder",
   c.alias AS "coin"
   , count(pp.Value) as "ContadorPagosPendientes"
   , sum(pp.Value) as "TotalPagosPendientes"
   FROM "banksAccounts" AS ba
   INNER JOIN holders AS h ON ba.idholder = h.idholder
   INNER JOIN coins AS c ON ba.idcoin = c.idcoin
   INNER JOIN banks AS b ON ba.idbank = b.idbank
   RIGHT JOIN shops AS s ON ba.idbankaccount = s.idbankaccount
   LEFT JOIN "usersShops" AS us ON s.idshop = us.idshop
   RIGHT JOIN users AS u ON u.iduser = us.iduser
   left join "paymentsPending" as pp on pp.idShop = s.idShop
   WHERE s.idshop = '59'
   group by
     u.type
   , u.state 
   , u.email
   , u.cellphone
   , s.name
   , s.idshop
   , u.iduser
   , b.name
   , ba.number
   , h.name
   , h.document
   , c.alias
   ;
   ```

## Aviso

El código publicado puede contener errores, fue escrito directamente en el editor de la respuesta para efectos didácticos. No tengo a mano el motor de base de datos, ni la estructura, para validar la sintaxis.  También fue escrito con el estándar SQL en mente, y no necesariamente con las particularidades del dialecto de [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql), queda como ejercicio para el lector validar la sintaxis y adaptar la respuesta a su necesidad específica.